# Land with wingsuit

Tags: pc, just-cause-3

I've seen gameplay where someone was flying the wingsuit and then they "pulled in" the wings so they would stop flying. I cannot figure out how to do is. I always need to land by parachuting first. Which is much slower than just "stop" the wingsuiting and land on your feet.

So how to do this? What button do I need to press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple mods later in the wingsuit tree which allow you to first slow down and retract the wingsuit when near the ground, and later to retract the wingsuit immediately while grappling.